# post value not getting on codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to get post value in Controller so that I had done my code like this.
The Controller looks like this

```
public function save_expense($id = NULL)
{
   $data['amount'] = $this->input->post('amount',TRUE);
   var_dump($data['amount'] );
   print_r($data['amount']);
}
```

My View file looks like this

```
 <form class="col s12"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/transactions/save_expense/<?php if (!empty($expense_info)) { echo $expense_info->transactions_id;}?>" method="post">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input placeholder="Amount"  type="text"  required name="amount" id="amount" value="<?php if (!empty($expense_info)) {echo $expense_info->amount;}?>">
                    <label for="amount"><?= lang('amount') ?></label>
        </div>
     </div>
    <div class="btn-area">
       <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light " type="submit" name="action">Update </button>
    </div>
 </form>
```

My .htaccess file looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(application) - [F,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm not getting any value that is passing to the controller, Please help me to solve my problem

Comment: What is it doing?

Comment: Is it calling the controller? Comment everything in save_expense() function and add echo "test";exit; to check your controller is being called or not

Comment: @TimBrownlaw its showing null value

Comment: @usmanikram yaa its calling the controller

Comment: What about print_r($this->input->post());

Comment: @TimBrownlaw it also shows null is it a problem of using material design

Answer (score 1):

I tested it and it's working fine. See code below and check if there's a difference

HTML

```
<form class="col s12" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo site_url();?>/extras/transactions/12333" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input placeholder="Amount" type="text" required name="amount" id="amount">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-area">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light " type="submit" name="action">Update</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP

```
  function transactions($id = NULL){
    echo "ID: ".$id;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "AMOUNT: ".$this->input->post('amount',TRUE);
  }
```

OUTPUT

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8Rqo.png

Comment: am using material design here will it be a cause

Comment: the code looks great and doesn't  have any changes with my code

Comment: No, can you check if your really redirecting to the right page? if yes try to output the id and the amount

  function transactions($id = NULL){
    echo "ID: ".$id;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "AMOUNT: ".$this->input->post('amount',TRUE);
  }

Comment: Some servers are case sensitive. try to change your file's name capitalization

Comment: when i pass the url like this from the function `redirect('admin/project/project_details/'. $amount);` its getting error like undefined variable

Comment: @user_777 what you are seeing now is a totally different issue. There is no mention of any redirects in your provided code. Are you sure your files on your localhost matches your server etc... I would mark this one (@Riyenz) answer as accepted and start a new question with the correct code relating to this provided...